# To which side should a bi-fold door open?

Tags: doors, door-frame

I will install a bi-fold door in my house, but the jambs here in Brazil already have rabbets for the door stops made in the jamb.

I'm trying to figure out where should the fold goes when the door is opened.

1) It could fold to the inside of the jamb (resting on the jamb when open).
[image]

2) Or it could fold to the outside of the jamb (with the two leaves outwards).
[image]

Which is the proper way of doing that? The second ways seems like the door corners should be rounded over so as to not hit the door stop, like the drawing below:
[image]

BTW: This hinges for bifold doors in Brazil have a handle in the center hinge.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, it depends which side of the door is the "public" side so to speak.

The door should be pull from the side that you open it from most often so you can use the handles.

It is hard to tell from your images, but I'm thinking the door leads to some sort of storage area so option 1 would be the best choice since you will open/close it from that side.

**Remember also...** Bi-Fold doors are really hard to close from the back-side without doing something weird to them to give you something to grip in the middle (as you have shown).... They are really not meant to be used as bi-directionally closable doors.

**UPDATE**

Clearing the rabbit hole.

In order to clear the rabbit and jamb, you need to move the pivot point a little further in. Moving the pivot points further in will allow the door to centre outside the jam when open as shown below. You may have to "Maguiver" the bottom bracket a bit if it does not let you go out that far. Remember when calculating the distance to the hole in the door to include space to allow the door to pivot.

The pin at the top on the other side of the door should be the same distance from the central door hinge as the pivot point hole.

[image]

With the swing the way you want it you would need to move the door out of the rabbit and add a piece of trim to the rabbit to create a new facia like below.

[image]

Personally. I's save myself a lot of fuss and bother and not use bifold-doors. I'd switch to the more modern French-door style.

[image]

Comment: The hinges for bifold doors here have a handle in the middle that does the function of closing it (I added a photo of the hinge in the post). One door will be between the bedroom and the closet and the other between the closet and the bathroom. The rabbets are on the side of the bedroom in the first case and the closet in the second.

Comment: I see @LuizBorges, interesting compromise they came up with. Still that's not too pretty for the user side. In your case you need the doors to fold OUT into the bedroom and the bathroom..

Comment: The one folding out into the bedroom must them have rounded corners all alond the edges to prevent it from binding and hitting the door stops (something that I would like to avoid if possible).

Comment: I'm not clear on that part @LuizBorges, that description is vague, you might want to show more detail there. Maybe a quick sketch.

Comment: Done, I added a sketch to the question.

Comment: well aint that a peach...

Comment: @LuizBorges, see my update

Comment: Option 3 is one of my choices, but I would still have a visible gap between the door and frame. Option 4 can't be done now due to the way it is installed. Option 5: will cause problems with the leaves having different sizes (since I'm not using a pivot). That leaves options 1 and 2...

Comment: not sure what you mean by "Option 5: will cause problems with the leaves having different sizes (since I'm not using a pivot). "

Comment: If I use a hinge instead of a pivot (like it is done on bifold doors) they won't line up when the door is open due to the hinge offset (the pivot point in in the outside of the door instead of in the middle of the door thickness).

Comment: oh riiight... I forgot about that bit.

Comment: OH WAIT A MINUTE..... Move the pivot point ! Move the hinge side away from the jam by the depth of the rabbit plus a bit . Do the same with the tracking pin on the other side.   When open it will clear the door jam and should not interfere with the frame any more than it does hanging it backwards. @LuizBorges

Comment: Just now I've seen your updated answer. After considering a lot of factors I will make them fold into the rooms they enter (my closet room and my bathroom), since those are more likely to be closed from the inside than from the outside. But now I have a doubt. What about if by chance the handle falls out or break. How can someone open the door from the inside since it must be pulled to open?

Comment: @LuizBorges, I'd sincerely switch to French doors. it takes approximately the same space, looks the same when closed, and it A LOT easier to install / use.

Comment: French doors are usually wider than the space I have available (800mm ou about 31 inches). They would look akward being so narrow and they would block light switches...

Comment: @LuizBorges Yes, you may have to tailor the doors to fit. However, folding doors are notoriously awkward to get started to close when fully open. I am concerned your wife is going to curse you every time she tries to close them with a hamper full of clothes under the other arm.

Answer (score 1):

A bifold door should "fold" into the "main room" and the hinges should be away from the "approach" side.

Comment: After considering a lot of factors I will make them fold into the rooms they enter (my closet room and my bathroom), since those are more likely to be closed from the inside than from the outside. But now I have a doubt. What about if by chance the handle falls out or break. How can someone open the door from the inside since it must be pulled to open?

Comment: If the handle breaks, you'll be able to reach down and grab the door in the middle and pull it towards you to open it.